# Use sql server database in Xamarin Android app

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am developing an Xamarin android app which will store data locally and sync to production server when needed. I have the production database and would like to replicate this locally. How would i achieve this within Xamarin. I am a new xamarin developer. Can i convert this database to sqllite. Thanks.

Comment: using sqlite is a good idea, we are using the same. Sqlite in app and sql server in production server.

Comment: @MunnaExtreme Thanks. Do you know how i could convert the sql server database to sqlLite.